# echo or print_r not printing anything

Tags: php

```
<form>
  <button name="submit1" value="submit" type="submit" class="btn red">Send Message</button>
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit1']) and !empty($_POST['submit1'])){
echo 'in';exit;
}
?>
```

I've a form and on submit on the same page i've php hat checks 'isset' or not. but i want to print on screen using print_r()? echo 'test';, but its not printing anything. Please help soon anybody

Comment: If you don't specify a method the default method is GET and not POST

Comment: You're submitting via `GET`, since you didn't put `method="POST"` into your `<form>`

Comment: You do know that the value will get in the $_POST after the form is submitted, right?

Comment: plus `!empty($_POST['submit1']` will **never** be "empty"; it's a "submit" type and not "text" or other type of input, so you can get rid of that conditional.

Comment: People are not interested in marking and up-voting the answer an telling problem is solved or not? Really frustrating. Wastage of effort. deleting my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Remember to specify the form method:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
  <button name="submit1" value="submit" type="submit" class="btn red">Send Message</button>
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit1']) && !empty($_POST['submit1'])){
    echo 'in';
    exit;
}
?>
```